# ASP.Net Core 3.0 app startup exception 'There is an incomplete parameter in the route template'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a really confusing issue, mainly because the exception I'm getting is very unhelpful and non-descriptive.

I have an ASP.Net Core-based API, and have just added a new controller. I am using ASP.Net Core 3.0, and am mapping my controllers within Startup.Configure by using the following:

`app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });`

However, when running the API in debug I was getting the following exception on startup:

> **RoutePatternException: There is an incomplete parameter in the route template. Check that each '{' character has a matching '}' character.**

I removed the controller and the issue disappears, so I figure there's something wrong with the controller that's causing the endpoint mapping to throw this exception but I can't see what it is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was only when I reconfigured how endpoints were routed that I found the answer to the problem. I've written this out in case anybody else gets any non-descriptive exceptions from ASP.Net Core. Within Startup.Configure, I replaced:

`app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });`

with:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute("repo1", "{controller=Repo1Controller}");
    routes.MapRoute("repo2", "{controller=Repo2Controller}");
}
```

Then in Startup.ConfigureServices, I added:

`services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);`

Upon next startup this then showed the following exception:

> **RouteCreationException: The following errors occurred with attribute routing information: For action: 'MyAPI.Controllers.Repo2Controller.UpdateEntityProperty (MyAPI)'**
>
> **Error: There is an incomplete parameter in the route template. Check that each '{' character has a matching '}' character. (Parameter 'routeTemplate')**

In the `Repo2Controller` I had the following:

```
[HttpPut("{entityId}/Properties/{propertyId")]
public IActionResult UpdateEntityProperty(string entityId, string propertyId)
{
    // Do some stuff
}
```

This highlighted the fact that I was missing the closing `}` in the `HttpPut` attribute. Once I replaced this and returned to the original endpoint routing method, everything worked fine.

Comment: Is the routes.MapRoute("repo1", "{controller=Repo1Controller}"); a file or function?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap Configure() method code with `try catch` like below.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        try
        {
            ...

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            ...

        }
        catch (System.Exception exp)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Then investigate the thrown exception. Under InnerException->Pattern you will find the specific problem. Sample: [image]